What are these 16-Century Italian monetary symbols?
I am trying to read a part of Tartaglia's General Trattato Di Numeri, Et Misure.  I have problems with what appear to be shorthand symbols for monetary or weight values.  I will be grateful if someone could help me.  
A sentence that begins in L. 4 reads:

overo multiplicame ducati 13. & 19. piccoli 26 per &&& 5. & & 14.

The ampersands are stand-ins for symbols that I don't understand.
Further, L.5 reads:

over quest'altra multiplicame L 15 & 5. sazzi 4 & 13 . . .

I could identify L for pound and I know sazzi is a smaller currency unit.  But I don't recognise other symbols.
Thanks.

Not Pound, but Lira. Dont delete here, I have an answer almost ready.

These are symbols representing Venetian coin values. Most of them are mentioned directly in the lines you are looking at: Ducati, Lira, Soldi, and Pizzoli.  An article here shows another page where four of these symbols are mentioned,

and provides the translation of the four symbols.

The circled symbols denote units of Venetian currency: ducats, lire,
soldi, and pizzoli.

(The wikipedia page for Lira explains some of the relationships between these coin values.)

Grazie mille.  Something you wrote enabled me to reach these tables.  The monstrosity at L. 4 towards the end is still to be cracked, but thank you!

I found out that it is the symbol for ducato corrente.  Thank you all the way.
